# Why is $\int^\pi_{-\pi} (2-|x|) \cos(x) = 4?$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I trying to find Fourier series and I see a lot of times that $\int^\pi_{-\pi}$ of absolute $|\cos| \text{ and } |\sin| $ is 4.

for example, $\int^\pi_{-\pi} (2-|x|) \cos(x) = 4 \text{ and } \int^\pi_{-\pi} |\sin(x)| = 4$.

What is the trick behind integrals over $[-\pi, \pi]$ of absolute-valued cosine and sine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

The integrand $f(x)=(2-|x|) \cos(x)$ is an even function on $I=[-\pi,\pi]$, so $$\int_I f(x)dx=2\color{blue}{\int_0^{\pi}(2-x)\cos(x)dx}=2\times\color{blue}{2}$$

[image]

Comment: Hello Babak. good approach.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^\pi_{-\pi} (2-|x|) \cos(x)dx=\int^{0}_{-\pi} (2+x) \cos(x)dx+ \int^\pi_{0} (2-x) \cos(x)dx$$

Comment: Nice to see you here. :)

Answer (score 1):

because
$$\int^\pi_{-\pi} (2-|x|) \cos(x)\,dx=2\int^\pi_0 (2-x) \cos(x)\,dx$$
s0
\begin{align*}
\int^\pi_0 (2-x) \cos(x)\,dx&=2\int_0^\pi\cos x\,dx-\int_0^\pi x\cos x\,dx\\
&=2\sin x\Bigg|_0^\pi -x\sin x\Bigg|_0^\pi +\int_0^\pi\sin x\,dx\\
&=-\cos x\Bigg|_0^\pi=2
\end{align*}
so
$$\int^\pi_{-\pi} (2-|x|) \cos(x)\,dx=4$$